# VBA Date + TimeValue returns no time

Tags: excel, vba, date, time

I have a date and time which I assemble into a date + time from strings in the form

```
date_string = "2020-12-30" 'yyyy-mm-dd    
date_code = CDate(date_string)

time_string = "00:00:00" 'hh:mm:ss
time_code = TimeValue(time_string)

date_time = date_code + time_code
```

Commonly the return looks like `05.01.2019 11:00:00`, which is what I expect.

The returned values also all check out as TRUE if I test with `IsDate(date_time)`

Whenever the time is `00:00:00` however, I only get the date returned with no time appended. I dont quite understand this, since `TimeValue(time_string)`returns `00:00:00`.

So it must be an issue when combining date and time to a date + time string.

Can someone please enlighten me why midnight somehow does no exist in Excel VBA or where my error in creating the time code is?

EDIT:

I try to explain my situation a bit better:

I do this date date/time stuff in code and then but the result in an array in a loop. Only later on it is written to a cell in a table.

By the time is is written into a cell, even custom formatting the cell to "DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm" does not show the time as it is completely missing from the cell value.

Do I neet to apply a format at the point of `date_code + time_code`?

Comment: Have you tried formatting the cells to include the time? The default date format does not include the time if it is zero.

Comment: Dates and times are numbers that represent a time since a given date (day 1 is `01/01/1900`).  Add whole numbers to increase the days, and fractional numbers to increase the time.  Midnight (`00:00:00`) is used to represent the start of the day (e.g. `1.0` is midnight on `01/01/1900`), and the time is usually omitted by Excel if no formatting is applied to a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the answer can be so simple. Thanks to Variatus and Paul I checked formatting out.

I applied a `date_time = Format(date_code + time_code, "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm")` in my code. Using this, my code runs as expected and `00:00:00` appears as expected, even in the cell values of the Excel table.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter an integer, like 43930, in a cell Excel will record the number as an integer, just as you entered it. You can then proceed to format the cell as `#,##0.000` and thereby make the number display as 43930.000. Or you can format that very same number as custom `dd mmm yyy hh:mm:ss` and display it as *09 Apr 2020 00:00:00*. The point is that Excel chose to record the number in its most efficient way, as an integer.

So, if you enter a DateValue + TimeValue which, together, amount to an integer Excel will record the integer correctly. The format in which that integer is displayed in your worksheet is a matter for cell formatting.

Comment: Dates (and Times) are stored as `Double`, not as `Integer`. An Integer doesn't have any fraction part that is needed for the time part.

Comment: @FunThomas You are absolutely right. VBA does use a Double data type to do Date/Time calculations. However, since 43930 has no decimal digits it's an integer even if you assign it to a variable of Double data type. I think even 1234567890 is an integer, not because it can be assigned to that data type in VBA but because it has no decimal digits.

Comment: I think talking about Integer leads to confusion. Functions like `CDate` or `TimeValue` return VarType 7 (`vbDate`), which is internally represented as `Double`. In case of `00:00`, the fraction part is simply 0, but the value is `43930.0`, not `43930`. BTW: even if you put an integer in a cell and read it into VBA, you will get a `Double` (Vartype 5).